# Uploading a file in PHP and getting the details of the file

Tags: php, html

I have the following code which accepts a file and uploads it and then displays the details of the file. The coding is in PHP. But I am unable to execute the code. I am using Wamp as my server. Please help me. 
EXAMPLE.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploadFile.php">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
</body>
```

uploadFile.php

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td>Client Filename: </td> <td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Type: </td> <td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Size: </td> <td>" . ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Name of Temp File: </td><td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Define "I am unable to execute the code". Do you get an error? what happens? what is supposed to happen

Comment: Basic uploads are covered extensively in the manual.

Comment: you are unable to execute? tell us what is the output you getting

Comment: I am getting a table as follows
Client Filename:  " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "
File Type:  " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] .
File Size:  " . ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb
Name of Temp File:  " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . "

Answer (score 2):

You didn't open your PHP file correctly, try:

```
<?php
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td>Client Filename: </td> <td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Type: </td> <td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>File Size: </td> <td>" . ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Name of Temp File: </td><td>" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following tag to the start of your uploadFile.php

```
<?php
```

to indicate that it should be parsed for PHP.  Everything worked OK